# Проблема с кросс-браузерностью

Tags: html, css

Столкнулся с данной проблемой. В хроме и опере сайт отображается нормально, но вот в firefox один экран поехал. Как эту проблему решить?

**Chorme:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**firefox:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.the-best {
  position: relative;
  top: -63%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  left: 4.5em;
  width: 20em;
}

.fotos {
  height: auto;
  width: 3em;
  position: relative;
  top: -32.5em;
  left: 9em;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

.fotos2 {
  height: auto;
  width: 3em;
  position: relative;
  top: -32.5em;
  left: 9em;
  display: table-cell;
  margin-top: 5em;
  left: 40em;
  top: -56.5em;
}

.mini-text {
  color: #009df5;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  top: -69.5em;
  left: 14em;
  width: 20em;
  line-height: 1em;
}

.big-text {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  top: -69.5em;
  left: 14em;
  width: 20em;
  top: -47em;
  left: 9.3em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.obrazovanie {
  top: -45.5em;
}

.stajirovki {
  top: -45.5em;
}

.mini-text2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  top: -69.5em;
  left: 14em;
  width: 20em;
  left: 45em;
  top: -91em;
  color: #009df5;
}

.big-text2 {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  top: -69.5em;
  left: 14em;
  width: 20em;
  top: -61.5em;
  left: 30em;
  font-weight: bolder;
}

.sertificates {
  top: -60em;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="the-best">Для вас работают лучшие</br>сервисные инженеры Москвы</br>и области</h1>
<img src="img/zvezda.png" alt="" class="fotos">
<img src="img/lampocka.png" alt="" class="fotos">
<img src="img/document.png" alt="" class="fotos">
<img src="img/grafik.png" alt="" class="fotos2">
<img src="img/diplom.png" alt="" class="fotos2">
<h4 class="mini-text">Только</h4>
<h2 class="big-text">профессиональные</br>инструменты</h2>
<h2 class="big-text obrazovanie">Образовательные</br>программы</h2>
<h4 class="mini-text">для штатных мастеров</h4>
<h2 class="big-text stajirovki">Стажировки</br>и обучение</h2>
<h4 class="mini-text">у производителей техники</h4>
<h4 class="mini-text2">Многоуровневый</h4>
<h2 class="big-text2">контроль</br>качества</h2>
<h2 class="big-text2 sertificates">Сертификаты</br>и лицензии</h2>
<h4 class="mini-text2">у всех мастеров</h4>
```

Comment: Ваш макет совершенно не так верстается. Концепцию position-relative-absolute вы понимаете абсолютно неверно.

Comment: Ой, страх то какой