# не работает @media

Tags: html, css

Всем привет! Это можно сказать продолжение моих граблей в процессе адаптации сайта:) В общем адаптировал я одну страницу, все зашибись. Приступаю я к второй странице. Прописываю 
`@media all and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1601px){}` который прекрасно работал на первой странице. 
Пишу внутри стили. А они не применяются. В инспекторе @media нету. И вот что делать не знаю. @media находиться в конце файла. В интернете ничего толкового не нашел:(

```
@media all and (max-width: 1536px) and (min-width: 1501px) {
  .block__three-block-bank-text-grey-two{
    left: 14%;
  }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот на скрине в элементах видно что @media нету.
cсылка на сайт: https://websitetestingfreelance.000webhostapp.com/banks.html

```
    @font-face {
font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Light.eot');
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Light.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Light.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold';
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.eot');
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Proxima Nova Extra Bold';
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Extrabld.eot');
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Extrabld.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Extrabld.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNova-Extrabld.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
@font-face {
font-family: 'Proxima Nova Thin';
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaT-Thin.eot');
src: url('../fonts/ProximaNovaT-Thin.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNovaT-Thin.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/ProximaNovaT-Thin.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
*{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body{
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.header{
  width: 100%;
  height: 3vw;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 0px 25px 250px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
.header-logo{
  position: absolute;
  top: 1%;
  left: 15%;
}
.header-menu-nav-button{
  height: 5%;
  width: 2.5%;
  top: 0.5%;
  right: 15%;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-lines{
  width: 80%;
  height: 7%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  background: #5cd648;
  margin-top: 21%;
}
.second-menu-line{
  width: 40%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 49%;
}
.third-menu-line{
  width: 65%;
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 26%;
}
.block__one{
  width: 100%;
  height: 30vw;
  position: relative;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFB522 0%, #FFBC2F 27.08%, #FEBB2B 53.65%, #FFB410 79.17%, #FDA400 89.06%, #EF9501 100%);
}
.block__one-img{
  position: absolute;
  right: -10%;
  bottom: 0;
}
.block__one-credit{
  color: white;
  font-size: 64px;
  width: 65%;
  top: 25%;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  letter-spacing: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 15%;
  line-height: 90px;
}
span{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Extra Bold';
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.buttom-arrow{
  position: absolute;
  left: 5%;
  top: 25%;
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
.block__one-input{
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 18%;
  top: 70%;
  left: 15%;
  height: 4vw;
  position: absolute;
}
.block__one-buttom{
  background: #5CD648;
  border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
  width: 18%;
  top: 70%;
  left: 32.8%;
  height: 4vw;
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.block__one-buttom-text{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 36%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold';
  font-size: 16px;
}
.bottom-text{
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 36%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold';
  font-size: 16px;
}
.block__one-input-text__grey{
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  color: #7A7C80;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin-left: 30%;
  left: -20%;
  top: 15%;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.block__one-input-text__bold{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Bold';
  font-size: 24px;
  float: left;
  top: 15%;
  margin-left:15%;
  left: -5.5%;
  position: relative;
}
.input-text{
  font-size: 13px;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.block__two{
  width: 100%;
  height: 25vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 30%;
}
.block__two-text__main{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 42px;
  left: 14%;
  top:10%;
  position: absolute;
}
.text-main{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 42px;
  left: 14%;
  top:10%;
  position: absolute;
}
.block__two-text-sub-grey{
  color: #989898;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  position: relative;
  left: 14%;
  top: 23%;
}
.block__two-block-bank{
  background: #FFFFFF;
  box-shadow: 5px 0px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: relative;
  left: 14%;
  width: 75%;
  top: 40%;
  height: 7vw;
}
.block__two-bank__logo{
  top: 23%;
  left: 2%;
  position: absolute;
}
.block__two-recomendation-text{
  color: #FFB522;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  position: absolute;
  top: 65%;
  left: 3.1%;
}
.block__two-block-bank-line{
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid #F7F7F7;
  left: 15%;
}
.block__two-block-bank-text-grey{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #7A7C80;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  left: 13%;
  top: 30%;
}
.text-grey{
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #7A7C80;
  font-size: 13px;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 5%;
  left: 13%;
  top: 30%;
}
.block__two-bank-block-text__black{
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  text-transform: uppercase;
  left: -47%;
  top: 50%;
}
.block__two-bank-block-text__black-one{
  color: #5cd648;
}
.block__two-bank-block-text__black-two{
  left: -40.5%;
}
.block__two-bank-block-text__black-three{
  left: -34.8%;
}
.block__two-bank-block-text__black-fore{
  left: -30.6%;
}
.block__two-bank-block-text__black-five{
  left: -24.4%;
}
.block__two-bank-block-text__black-six{
  left: -20.8%;
}
.block__two-block-bank-buttom{
  position: absolute;
  width: 15%;
  left: 81.5%;
  top: 28%;
  height: 40%;
  background: #5CD648;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  box-shadow: 0px 4px 10px rgba(92, 214, 72, 0.15);
  border-radius: 100px;
}
.block__two-buttom-text{
  font-size: 13px;
}
.block__three{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 70vw;
  top: 0vw;
}
.block__three-clock-img{
  position: absolute;
  top: 3.4%;
  right: 40%;
}
.block__three-update{
  position: absolute;
  font-family: 'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  color: #989898;
  font-size: 18px;
  top: 3.6%;
  right: 21%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey{
  top: 7vw;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-one{
  left: 12.3%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-two{
  left: 12%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-three{
  left: 9.5%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-fore{
  left: 8.4%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-five{
  left: 7.1%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-six{
  left: 5.7%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-six{
  left: 5.7%;
}
.block__three-block-bank-text-grey-seven{
  left: 5%;
}
.block__three-text__main{
  top: 2%;
}
.block__three-block-bank{
  position: relative;
  top: 15%;
  margin-top: 1%;
}
.block__hree-bank-block-text__black{
  left: 12%;
  top: 42%;
  margin-left: 5%;
}
.block__three-bank-text__black-block__one{
  top: 10%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  left:22.4%;
}
.bank-block-three-25{
  top: 40%;
  left:-75.5%;
}
.bank-block-three-green{
  color: #5cd648;
  font-size: 25px;
}
.block__three-recomendation-text-two{
  color: #2D4D7A;
}
.block__three-recomendation-text-three{
  color: #FE471F;
}
.block__three-recomendation-text-fore{
  color: #5CD648;
}
.block__borrower{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0vw;
}
.block__borrower-img{
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 22%;
  left: -13%;
  top: 8vw;
}
.block__borrower-img-two{
  top: 7.2vw;
}
.block__borrower-img-three{
  top: 6.5vw;
}
.block__borrover-text__sub{
  font-family:'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  margin-left: 5.2%;
  left: 9%;
  top: 20%;
  position: relative;
}
.block__yellow{
  position: relative;
  width: 75%;
  background: #FFB522;
  height: 25vw;
  margin: auto;
  top: 0vw;
}
.block__fore{
  background: #FEB71F;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  height: 28vw;
  top: 0vw;
}
.block__yellow{
  background: #FEB71F;
  position: relative;
  width: 70%;
  left:14%;
  height: 28vw;
  top: 0vw;
}
.block__fore-text__main{
  color: white;
  left: 4%;
}
.block__fore-blocks__mini{
  position: relative;
  height: 18%;
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  top: 32%;
  margin-left: 3.9%;
}
.block__fore-blocks__big{
  position: relative;
  height: 32%;
  float: left;
  width: 28%;
  top: 41%;
  margin-left: 3.9%;
}
.block__fore-img{
  position: relative;
  top: 1vw;
}
.block__fore-block__text{
  font-family:'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: white;
  left: 7%;
  position: relative;
}
.block__six{
  width: 100%;
  height: 15vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0vw;
}
.block__six-block__grey{
  width: 100%;
  height: 20vw;
  top:-5vw;
  z-index: -1;
  position: absolute;
  background: #1C2331;
}
.block__grey-img{
  position: relative;
  top: 35.5%;
  left: 15.5%;
}
.block__grey-img-two{
  top: 47%;
  left: 14.3%;
}
.block__grey-img-three{
  top: 57.8%;
  left: 13.1%;
}
.block__grey-img-fore{
  top: 69.5%;
  left: 12%;
}
.block__grey-img-five{
  top: 81%;
  left: 10.85%;
}
.block__grey-text{
  font-family:'Proxima Nova Light';
  color: white;
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 15px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 17%;
  top: 35%;
}
footer{
  background: #131925;
  width: 100%;
  height: 4vw;
  position: relative;
  top: 0vw;
}
.footer__copyrating{
  color: #7A8291;
  font-family:'Proxima Nova Light';
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  top: 38%;
  left: 15%;
  position: absolute;
}
.footer__polytics{
    font-family:'Proxima Nova Light';
    font-size: 15px;
    text-transform: 12px;
    color: white;
    text-decoration-line: underline;
    top: 38%;
    right: 15%;
    position: absolute;
    cursor: pointer;
}
@media all and (max-width: 1536px) and (min-width: 1501px) {
  .block__three-block-bank-text-grey-two{
    left: 14% !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: Выложите Вашу разметку и стиль, чтобы можно было воспроизвести проблему и найти ошибку.

Comment: Добавил css код, html не поместился. Так же дал ссылку на страницу

Comment: этот https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1055529/%d0%9f%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b0-%d1%81-%d0%ba%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%81-%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%83%d0%b7%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%8e ?

Comment: не, это совсем другой сайт. У меня сегодня был просто еще один вопрос по адаптации этого сайта

Comment: другой разметки Вы нигде больше не выкладывали.

Comment: Да, разметку я нигде не кидал. Вот тот вопрос что был сегодня мною задан.https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1071644/%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%bb%d1%8e%d1%87%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%be-500px-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b0-desktop

Comment: Я не могу из-за ограничений выложить html код

Comment: Вопрос принято задавать таким образом, чтобы была возможность конкретно понять суть проблемы, а так же возможность её воспроизвести https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Вот код html, css: https://repl.it/repls/PreviousWrathfulFiber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если нужен диапазон - то у Вас написано корректно. Просто ширину Вы вводите очень большую. Попробуйте от 1200 до 1000. (протестировано)

```
 @media all and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 1000px) { //Добавить , and
        .block__three-block-bank-text-grey-two{
            left: 14% !important;
        }
    }
```

Ширина 1430px
[image: Ширина 1430px]

Ширина 1180px
[image: Ширина 1180px]

Ширина 977px
[image: Ширина 977px]

Если Вы хотите задать несколько параметров, например для для `screen` ширину `1000`, а для `all` другую, то указывать и надо через запятую.

```
 @media all and (max-width: 1200px), screen and (min-width: 1000px) { //Добавить , and
        .block__three-block-bank-text-grey-two{
            left: 14% !important;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!

Comment: Хм, а почему оно применяет на все разрешения а не от 1501 до 1536?

Comment: @Скалетта Так, если для диапазона, то у Вас правильно было написано. Просто слишком широкое. Вы уменьшите его с 1200 по 1000 и посмотрите при изменении экрана.

Comment: Denis640Kb, Можете поподробней объяснить? И у меня тут с страницей какой то бред происходит. То она видит @media, то оно ее не видит, ужс

Comment: @Скалетта, когда Вы меняете разрешение экрана - у Вас `@media` меняет стили. Например, если Вы в первом примере будете менять разрешение экрана - когда он станет меньше 1200 и больше 1000, включится стиль. Если уменьшите ещё - меньше 1000, то стиль опять вернётся в изначальное состояние.

Comment: Да, я знаю. Но прикол то в том что у меня стоит max-width 1920px а min-width 1800px, а оно все равно стили применяет к любому разрешению, будто 800px или 1500px. Все будет так как на 1920

Comment: @Скалетта дополнил ответ скринами. Вы точно указали корректный запрос `@media`, как в первом примере? Протестировал у себя - всё работает. На скринах видно.

Comment: Вижу. Да, я указал корректный запрос. Очень странно то что на 1200 оно работает, а на 1920px оно не работает

Comment: https://imgur.com/geY2yta          @media all and (max-width: 1920px) and (min-width: 1800px) {  //Добавить , and
    .bottom-text{
      top: 20px;
    }
   }

Comment: @Скалетта, так у Вас ширина экрана больше 1800? Протестировал у себя данные параметры с 1920 по 1600 (у меня макс 1620) - всё работает корректно.

Comment: Разрешение моего экрана 1600х900. Через chrome webtools врубил 1920х1080. И там нету @media

Comment: @Скалетта, протестировал у себя на другом компе, с разрешением в диапазоне 1920-1800 всё работает корректно. Скорее всего проблемы с Вашим webtools. Вы же понимаете, что 1920 - это ширина в Вашем разрешении, а 1080 - высота?

Comment: И правда. Посмотрел на другом пк с монитором 1920 и все есть. Вот это очень уже странно. Видать хром чуток с ума сошёл

Comment: В общем тут какая то мистика. Вернулся обратно за свой пк, перезагрузил хром, очистил кукки, а он все равно не видит media. Открыл оперу, и все нормально